# Meaning of "need but read"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, adverbs

I saw the sentence something like
"One need but read the depressing accounts of how people lived in London and other large British cities early in the 20th century to be grateful that the good old days are past."

I can partially understand what this sentence means but can not see whether it is correct in terms of grammar.

What does "need but read" means?

Answer (score 2):

It means "One only needs to read". However 'One' used like this is a third person singular pronoun like 'he', 'she' or 'it' so the sentence should read "One need**s** but read..." rather than "One need but read...".

The [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but) has a number of definitions for **but**, the most relevant of which in this context is 2c

> **with the exception of** — used before a word often taken to be the subject of a clause

Which has the example

> none but the brave deserves the fair

This example can be reworded as

> Only a brave men deserves a beautiful women

Again 'but' is used in the sense of 'only'

Answer (score 0):

**but**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25316?rskey=mHKuqz&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid)  A limiting a word or phrase.

> no more than

As in:

*"One need to **no more than** read the depressing accounts of how people lived in London ...*